# Compare type variants with a function

Tags: haskell

Is there a function that would allow for such a comparison

```hs
data Foo a = A a | B a

equal (A _) (A _) = True
equal (B _) (B _) = True
equal _ _ = False
```

How could I check something like

```hs
matches (B 42) (B _)
```

with a function that returns a boolean (without specifying the alternatives)?

Comment: This could only be answered with a lot of guesswork regarding what you're on about here. Properly phrase out type signatures and/or examples and discuss why a simplistic pseudo-code solution does not work.